# TAP interface generating same MAC address on multiple servers

Tags: vpn, mac-address

We use PeeerVPN on Debian 11 servers and we recognized that the TAP interfaces on multiple servers comes up with the same MAC address (it should be random generated).

Is anyone experienced the same problem? Does anyone know how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Debian 11 start set MAC address based on /etc/machine-id. Just regenerate it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403054